# Focusing on particular information within a cell when doing a calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When performing a calculation using two cells in Excel, is there a way to focus on specific information within a cell, when entering the formula?

For example, I have two time cells (start time and stop time), but the format of the time is: 2013-03-25T09:50:26.469+02

Thus, I cannot simply subtract one cell from the other (i.e. `=A1-B1`)....

I just want to be able to focus in on the "09:50" from the above cell.

Comment: And using a formula to return the hour + minute from each doesn't work? e.g. =HOUR(A1) or =MINUTE(A1)

Answer (score 2):

If excel recognises them as valid dates, then you can just extract hh:mm details using the following (assuming C4 has data):

```
=CONCATENATE(HOUR(C4),":",MINUTE(C4))
```

Else, assuming your data is formatted in the manner you mention you just need to extract the middle part of the string:

```
=MID(CellWithData,12,5)
```

Tell excel to format the resuting info as 'Time' and you will be able to subtract them